# Can not delete post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

There is an application written on rails and angular. The application is simple, all about taking data from the database and displaying them in the application table. After this, conduct various manipulations with them. The application can add data to the database and save the changes.
But the problem is that can not delete the data.
When you try to uninstall, the console displays the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'chock_diameter_id' of undefined
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 14, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

If anyone knows how to fix it, please help.

Comment: what are you trying to do. can you add more information

Comment: In `this.sprChockDiameter.chock_diameter_id` `this.sprChockDiameter` is not defined. Did you pass it as an input?

Comment: @Aravind I want to implement a button to delete information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change :

```
this.servSprChockDiameter.deleteSprChockDiameter(this.sprChockDiameter.chock_diameter_id)
```

to

```
this.servSprChockDiameter.deleteSprChockDiameter(sprChockDiameter.chock_diameter_id)
```

---

Change this :

```
'spr_chock_diameters/${id}'
```

to

```
`spr_chock_diameters/${id}`
```

For More Detail : **[Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**

Comment: It did not help me

Comment: Please post the value of `sprChockDiameter` and from where its coming ?

Comment: in Component.ts laid out a little more in more detail without saving, changing, etc.

Comment: Please post  the value of `sprChockDiameter` insdide `deleteSprChockDiameter` , and post the parent component from where you are passing `sprChockDiameter`

Comment: Do not quite understand. Here: @Input() sprChockDiameter: SprChockDiameter;

Comment: @Yumi , it should be provided from the parent component , if you have no idea about that , please read about `@Input` first .

Comment: Okay , first thing I don't understand russian :) , Second if there is no parent component then dont use `@input` , Remove `@Input` line from your code there is no need of that , please share full html part

Comment: I'm sorry, by chance) I'll send it now)

Comment: @Yumi , remove `this` from `this.sprChockDiameter` in `deleteSprChockDiameter` , and it will work :) , check the updated answer

Comment: I tried so already, me another mistake throws DELETE http://10.12.4.109:5000/spr_chock_diameters/5 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Yumi , now thats the issue of server side , you have successfully made call to the server from angular , check the method type of that , Will you please upvote and accept the amswer also ?